# Was the close vote removed?

Tags: support, review

There is/was this review/close item: https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/35991

[image]
but the actual question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266387/
[image]

doesn't/didn't  show any close votes. Was the close vote removed?

PS: Now it does, but I still wonder...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that the question was flagged by a $<3,000$ user that it is off-topic. Such flags end up in the queue despite not having actual closing votes.

Generally speaking the closing votes may have expired, but this is not the case as the question is just one hour old.

Comment: Thanks Asaf....